# Table continuing over multiple pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I'm making a kind of "dictionary": vocabulary lists for school. I'm using a simple two column table and I'm perfectly happy with the way it looks and the way of entering the information in the source code, however the table goes on over the bottom margin of the page and isn't continued on the next page (I also get some error messages).

How can I change that, so that the contents of the table will end at the bottom margin and will be continued on the next page seamlessly. I could manually start new table enviroments when I see the page is full, but that doesn't seem very practical.

If you know an overall better approach to achieve my desired output, please let me know.

My code (it contains many entries to demonstrate the problem, so it's rather long sorry):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    
\section*{Strukturvokabular}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { 
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X 
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X }
    
en outre, de plus, en plus & desweiteren, außerdem, dazu... \\
d'abord & zunächst \\
en suite & \\
de la part de & von Seiten (+Gen.) \\
considerer comme & betrachten als \\
couramment & geläufig, üblicherweise, oft \\
principalment & vor allem \\
le rapport & der Bezug \\
par rapport à & bezüglich, in Bezug auf \\
comme si & als ob \\
également & gleichermaßen, ebenfalls \\
issu de qc. & aus etw. entstanden/hervorgegangen/stammend \\
valable & gültig \\
mener à & führen zu \\
la baisse & Rückgang, Abnahme \\
la hausse & Anstieg, Zunahme \\
lorsque, quand & wenn/als \\
au cours de  & im Laufe/während (+Gen.) \\
augmenter & vergrößern, zunehmen, steigen, verstärken \\
diminuer & abnehmen, verringern, mindern, abschwächen \\
même (si) & sogar (wenn) \\
exiger & (er)fordern \\
signifier & bedeuten \\
utiliser & verwenden, nutzen \\
agir sur qn./qc. & auf jmd./etw. einwirken \\
contenir & enthalten \\
la contenu & Inhalt \\
soutenir & unterstützen \\
malgré (tout) & trotz (allem) \\
la question être de savoir si/il s'agit de savoir si & es geht darum, ob \\
plus ... plus ... & je ... desto ... \\
quelques-uns & einige, welche, manche \\
il y en a qui & Es gibt welche, die... \\
il y a des jeunes/gens/personnes qui & Es gibt Jugendliche/Leute/Personen die \\
il y en a d'autres qui & Es gibt andere die \\
Il n'y a que peu des gens & Es gibt nur wenige Leute die \\
certains (personnes) & einige, bestimmte, manche (Personen) \\
se rendre compte de qc. & sich etw. bewusst werden/sein \\
(s')aggraver & (sich) verschlimmern/verschlechtern \\
douter de qc. & etw. bezweifeln/an etw. zweifeln \\
prétendre qc. & etw. behaupten/vorgeben etw. zu tun \\
la minorité, la majorité & Minderheit, Mehrheit \\
unique & einzig(artig) \\
empêcher & verhindern \\
favoriser & fördern, begünstigen, bevorzugen \\
essayer/tenter qc. & etw. probieren/versuchen \\
séparer & trennen \\
valable & gültig \\
autoriser/permettre & erlauben
interdire/défendre qc. à qn. & jmd. etw. verbieten \\
le moyen & Mittel \\
consister en & bestehen aus \\
supposer & vermuten \\
domaine & Gebiet, Bereich \\
il vaut mieux faire qc. & es ist besser etw. zu tun \\
échouer & scheitern \\
décès & Todesfall \\
lieu & Ort \\
aussi bien ... que & ebenso ... wie \\
dès que & sobald, sowie 


\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply load the `xltabular` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to tabularx, and replace the latter environment with the eponymous environment. Unrelated: needless to load array if you load tabularx.

Comment: @Bernard I'm sorry I don't understand. What exactly do I replace with what? Do I just change the argument of the `\begin` environment, if yes to what? longtable or xltabular?

Comment: `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ >{\raggedright}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X }……\end{xltabular}`. Also, use the syntax from `longtable` for the table headers and footers.

Comment: Your code is not compilable since a `\\ ` is missing after "erlauben".

Comment: thank you both very much, it's now working fine as intended :)